# Deactivate actionbuttons based on row length in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the `shiny` app below in which when the user clicks on a row of the datatable a subset happens in another dataframe `df` and a text is displayed.

When I press the `Next` `actionbutton()` the text displayes the data of the next row of the subseted dataframe.

When I press the `Previous` `actionbutton()` the text displayes the data of the previous row of the subseted dataframe.

But when the row is the first the `actionbutton() 'Previous'` should be deactivated because there is no previous row and when the row is the last the `actionbutton() 'Next'` should be deactivated because there is no next row. So when they are clicked under these condition the message should remain the same.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                  textOutput("celltext"),
                  actionButton("next","Next"),
                  actionButton("prv","Previous")),
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(text=NULL)
    dt <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    output$tableId = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris[,c(1,5)],  selection = list(target = 'row',mode="single")
    )
    species<-c("setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica","setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica")
    flower<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
    score<-c(7,5,6,9,1,2,3,4)
    df<-data.frame(species,flower,score)
    
    observeEvent(input$tableId_rows_selected, {
      if(is.null(input$tableId_rows_selected)){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        row <- input$tableId_rows_selected
        dat<-df[df$species %in% iris[row,5],]
        dt$data <-dat[order(dat$score,decreasing = T),]
        rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[1,2],"has score",dt$data[1,3])
        rnum(1)
        
        output$celltext <- renderText({
          if(length(input$tableId_rows_selected))  rv$text
          else ''
        })
      }
      
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input[['prv']], {
      rnum(rnum()-1)
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
    })
    observeEvent(input[['next']], {
      rnum(rnum()+1)
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                  textOutput("celltext"),
                  actionButton("next","Next"),
                  actionButton("prv","Previous")),
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(text=NULL)
    dt <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
    rnumm <- reactiveVal(0)
    output$tableId = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris[,c(1,5)],  selection = list(target = 'row',mode="single")
    )
    species<-c("setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica","setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica")
    flower<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
    score<-c(7,5,6,9,1,2,3,4)
    df<-data.frame(species,flower,score)
    
    observeEvent(input$tableId_rows_selected, {
      if(is.null(input$tableId_rows_selected)){
        return(NULL)
      }
      else{
        row <- input$tableId_rows_selected
        dat<-df[df$species %in% iris[row,5],]
        dt$data <-dat[order(dat$score,decreasing = T),]
        rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[1,2],"has score",dt$data[1,3])
        rnum(1)
        rnumm(nrow(dat))
        output$celltext <- renderText({
          if(length(input$tableId_rows_selected))  rv$text
          else ''
        })
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input[['prv']], {
      if (rnum()>1) rnum(rnum()-1)
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
    })
    observeEvent(input[['next']], {
      if (rnum()<rnumm()) rnum(rnum()+1)
      rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know to really disable a ui element is with the `shinyjs` package. This way you do not only prevent the function from being executed but users can see that a next/previous action is not possible.

My example does the following:

1. Load shinyjs, of course, and also register is as first element of `fluidPage` as required.
2. It initialises the buttons as disabled. As long as the user ha not selected any rows, the buttons do not serve any purpose. We could also hide them, of course.
3. Once a row is selected, the disabled state of the two buttons is set accordingly (see first `observeEvent()`.
4. Every button click on prev/next shall re-evaluate the status of the buttons (the last two `observeEvent()`s on the buttons).

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    
    shinyApp(
      ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
                      DT::dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                      textOutput("celltext"),
                      disabled(actionButton("next","Next")),
                      disabled(actionButton("prv","Previous"))
                      ),
      
      server <- function(input, output) {
        rv <- reactiveValues(text=NULL)
        dt <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
        rnum <- reactiveVal(0)
        output$tableId = DT::renderDataTable(
          iris[,c(1,5)],  selection = list(target = 'row',mode="single")
        )
        species<-c("setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica","setosa","setosa","virginica","virginica")
        flower<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
        score<-c(7,5,6,9,1,2,3,4)
        df<-data.frame(species,flower,score)

        
        observeEvent(input$tableId_rows_selected, {
          if(is.null(input$tableId_rows_selected)){
            return(NULL)
          }
          else{
            row <- input$tableId_rows_selected
            dat<-df[df$species %in% iris[row,5],]
            dt$data <-dat[order(dat$score,decreasing = T),]
            rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[1,2],"has score",dt$data[1,3])
            rnum(1)
            
            output$celltext <- renderText({
              if(length(input$tableId_rows_selected))  rv$text
              else ''
            })
            
            shinyjs::toggleState(id = "prv", condition = rnum() > 1)
            shinyjs::toggleState(id = "next", condition = rnum() < nrow(dt$data))
          }
          
          
        })
        
        observeEvent(input[['prv']], {
          req(dt$data) # make sure this is only exeuted with a valid object `dt$data` 
          
          rnum(rnum()-1)
          rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
          shinyjs::toggleState(id = "prv", condition = rnum() > 1)
          shinyjs::toggleState(id = "next", condition = rnum() < nrow(dt$data))
        })
        observeEvent(input[['next']], {
          req(dt$data) # make sure this is only exeuted with a valid object `dt$data` 
          
                rnum(rnum()+1)
          rv$text <- paste("flower",dt$data[rnum(),2],"has score",dt$data[rnum(),3])
          
          shinyjs::toggleState(id = "prv", condition = rnum() > 1)
          shinyjs::toggleState(id = "next", condition = rnum() < nrow(dt$data))
        })
      }
    )
```